# How to pass parameters in gulp dependencies

Tags: parameters, dependencies, task, gulp

I'd like to prepare a different versions of a software by passing a special parameters in gulp task.

I've created tasks for css, js, etc. and made one to run then all:

`gulp.task('compile', ['css', 'twig', 'js', ....]);`

How to pass a parameter which will be passed also to the subtasks? Is there any way to do that?

I'd like to run e.g.:
`gulp compile --mode A`
and 
`gulp compile --mode B`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I'm use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) module

in gulpfile use:

```
var mode = require("yargs").argv.mode;
```

run task with:

```
gulp compile -mode A
```

In your [css/twig/etc] tasks use:

```
gulp.task("css", function(){
  var cssSRC = "./src/" + mode + "/*.css";
  gulp.src(cssSRC)
  ...
  ...
})
```